# gulp browser-sync игнорирует js файл с точкой в названии

Tags: gulp, browsersync

Пытаюсь сделать сборку на gulp, и плагин browser-sync почему-то отказывается видеть файл скрипта main.min.js  Если убрать или заменить точку перед min - все работает, при этом style.min.css - его вообще не смущает и все обновляется и видится))
В чем может быть проблема?

Без точки скрипт работает и я могу из консоли перейти в него, а с точкой выдает Cannot GET /js/main.min.js/   - в конце слэш, как-будто он воспринимает файл как папку??

Если прописать несуществующий файл, то последнего слэша в сообщении нет
Cannot GET /js/main__min.js
Если добавить еще точек, тоже этого слэша нет)

КОД:

```
const { src, dest, watch, parallel } = require("gulp");
const scss = require("gulp-sass")(require("sass"));
const concat = require("gulp-concat");
const autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
const uglify = require("gulp-uglify-es").default;
const browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

function browsersync() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "app",
    },
  });
}

function styles() {
  return src("app/scss/style.scss", { sourcemaps: true })
    .pipe(scss({ outputStyle: "compressed" }))
    .pipe(concat("style.min.css"))
    .pipe(
      autoprefixer({
        overrideBrowserslist: "last 10 version",
        grid: true,
      })
    )
    .pipe(dest("app/css", { sourcemaps: "." }))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function scripts() {
  return src("app/js/main.js", { sourcemaps: true })
    .pipe(concat("main.min.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(dest("app/js", { sourcemaps: "." }))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function watching() {
  watch(["app/scss/**/*.scss"], styles);
  watch(
    ["app/js/**/*.js", "!app/js/main.min.js.map", "!app/js/main.min.js"],
    scripts
  );
  watch(["app/*.html"]).on("change", browserSync.reload);
}

exports.default = parallel(scripts, browsersync, watching);
```

Структура:

[image: Структура проекта:]

Answer (score 0):

В общем, так и не понял, в чем была проблема, собирал по туториалу на ютубе. Думаю, что загвоздка в расположении исходников и результирующих файлов в одних и тех же папках.
Сделал сборку с нормальной структурой и данная проблема не возникла.